# how to refresh a page in asp.net using maessage box event

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want to do is, when I will click the message box "OK" button, it will reload the whole page.
This is the code for generating the message box.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                "alert('error!!  Try reloading the page!  ')", true);
```

This is the code for reloading the page.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

So, I want to catch the event generated by the "OK" button of the message box. And use it to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
         "alert('error!!  Try reloading the page!  ');location.reload();", true);
```

Or

This with option to chose to reload or not.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
             "if(confirm("error!!  Try reloading the page!")){location.reload();}", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
            "alert('error!!  Try reloading the page!  ');window.location.reload()", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but the thing is it keeps showing the dialogue box again and again.

Comment: because your code execute again. you must handle this situation why and when do you run it? if you have an error it true to show this dialog again but if not you must prevent rendering this.

Comment: Ok! I got it. Thanks again.